# Frame Animation callback when animation is complete in Android

Tags: android, animation, frame

Is it possible in Android to get a callback when a Frame Animation (AnimationDrawable) has completed playing its frame sequence?  I know when a Tween Animation has completed, it calls  onAnimationEnd(), but is there something similar for frame by frame animations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no way to know when the FrameAnimation ends.

Refer this: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214735/android-animationdrawable-and-knowing-when-animation-ends)

i suggest this method : [here](http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=128857303793437&topic=74)

Comment: Thanks for posting this info.  I guess I was searching the wrong keywords.

Comment: 2nd link seems broken to me (points to a non-existent facebook page). Any hint?

Comment: 2nd link still broken :/