# Android, How can I know that the animation is finished?

Tags: android, animation, button

In my project i have a button. when user clicks on it, it shows and animation after that should load another activity.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnReadPage:
                startAnimation();
                //stopAnimation();
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Read Page Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //startActivity(new Intent(this, ReadPage.class));
                return;
        }

    }
```

according to above code(startActivity, commented), when I run the application and click on the button, animation will play. but if i uncomment it because of fast transition animation doesn't show.
How can i inform that animation is finished?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750939/android-animation-is-not-finished-in-onanimationend

Comment: Check out the answer here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214735/android-animationdrawable-and-knowing-when-animation-ends

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On your animation object call this code:

```
am1.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {    
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // Pass the Intent to switch to other Activity

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Update 2023 in Kotlin. Following Rahulkapil answer.

```
val animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(requireContext(), R.anim.fade_in)

animation.fillAfter = true
animation.duration = 2000

animation.setAnimationListener(object : AnimationListener {
    override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation) {
        Log.d("////", "onAnimationStart")
    }

    override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation) {
        Log.d("////", "onAnimationRepeat")
    }

    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation) {
        Log.d("////", "onAnimationEnd")
        // Pass the Intent to switch to other Activity
    }
})
binding.myTextView.startAnimation(animation)
```