# How to stop AnimationDrawable after 2 repeat

Tags: android, android-animation, animationdrawable

I have made an animation using AnimationDrawable with images.It is running well. But I want to stop it after 2 repeat. How can I do this? Here is my codes.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    imageViewCark.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim);
    animation = (AnimationDrawable) imageViewCark.getBackground();

    if(hasFocus == true){
        animation.start();

    }else{
        imageViewCark.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
        animation.stop();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>Set an `AnimationListener` and in the `onAnimationRepeat` method you'll have to update a `counter` like `counter++`. When `counter == 2` stop it!</s>

Sorry mate, thought you used `Animation`. Check out this thread 
[Android AnimationDrawable and knowing when animation ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214735/android-animationdrawable-and-knowing-when-animation-ends/2922300#2922300).

By getting the current frame you can know when a repeat has went through, there is some code there for your problem.

Comment: I have implemented AnimationListener class and overrieded the methods. AnimationDrawable type is not suitible for this class.

Comment: What do you mean "is not suitible for this class", you stop the animation that you use in the overriden method. Add some code!

Comment: I have add some codes. How can I use AnimationListener with AnimationDrawable?

Comment: Alright, sorry mate. I misunderstood you, check my updated answer.