# Finish the animation on click before going to another activity

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an animation that is to be displayed on click of an image view and finish the animation before going to another activity.I have been trying to do this.

Here is my code :

```
public void myAnimation() 
    AnimationDrawable animation;
    animation = new AnimationDrawable();
    animation.addFrame(
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.large_ring_monotone),
            1000);
    animation.addFrame(getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.large_ring_eal), 1000);
    animation.addFrame(
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.large_ring_blue), 1000);
    animation.addFrame(
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.large_ring_monotone),
            1000);

    animation.setOneShot(true);
    img_big_2_back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener){
    img_big_2_back.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);

        try {
            animation.start();
            Thread.sleep(3000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent i1 = new Intent(MAinACtivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(i1);
    });
}
```

Can any one let me know where i am going wrong

Comment: Can you please describe what is actually going wrong?

Comment: object.clearAnimation();

Answer (score 3):

Man, if your activity is getting called even before animation is finished, then try setting Animation Listener, you can start activity from there once animation finish callback is received.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html

Comment: I cant use AnimationListener for AnimationDrawable , If i use Animation , then how to attach images to it

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why there is a `Thread Sleep` in your code? That's not the way to wait for animation to get over. Try the answers of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214735/android-animationdrawable-and-knowing-when-animation-ends). You can use the method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6641321/430480)