# how do i run AnimationDrawable 3 times

Tags: android, animation, frame, animationdrawable

Hi again everyone and thanks for your help last time. Thanks also for any help you all give me on this one!

So i have an `amimationDrawable` of a coinSpinning.

```
    <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/coinflip1" android:duration="25" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/coinflip2" android:duration="25" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/coinflip3" android:duration="25" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/coinflip4" android:duration="25" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/coinflip5" android:duration="25" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/coinflip6" android:duration="25" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/coinflip7" android:duration="25" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/coinflip8" android:duration="25" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/coinflip9" android:duration="25" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/coinflip10" android:duration="25" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/coinflip11" android:duration="25" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/coinflip12" android:duration="25" />
    </animation-list>
```

this is my method that spins the coin after a button onClick

```
    public void spinCoin(){

        final ImageView coinAmina = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        coinAmina.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.coin_spin_heads); 
        coinAmina.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) coinAmina.getBackground();
                frameAnimation.start();
            }
        }); 

        //end of coin spin
        }
```

i also have `AnimationDrawable frameAnimation;` before onCreate

it runs fine, but my problem has been trying to run it a certain amount of time eg 3
ive tried to loop the `coinSpin()` then `frameAnimation.stop` but no good

ive also tryed `Thread.sleep(500)` with `setOneShot(false)` then changed to `true` after the sleep

all i want to do is run the animation whatever amount of time i like.
other problem is when i have 2 coins to spin only one does but that should be another question

i understand `setOneshot(true)` runs it once and `false` runs it over and over...but how do i stop it

any help would be greatly appriciated

Comment: The easiest solution (maybe not the best one) I can think of is duplicating (well, actually triplicating) the items in your AnimationDawable.

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214735/android-animationdrawable-and-knowing-when-animation-ends

Comment: how come i carnt just loop it? or evan just frameAnimation.stop()?

Comment: @artoo if i was to duplicate it, how come when i press the button again it wont play again?