# Can i run animation drawable more then once?

Tags: android, animation, drawable

Can i run an `animationDrawable` more then once while `setOneShot()` is set to true?

Or if i do set `setOneShot` to `false` how can i stop it? `frameAnimation.stop()` after a `loop` doesn't work and the `loop` doesn't work with `setOneShot(true)`

I asked this in my previous Q, but the answer pointed to a post with several different answers making things more confusing.

Basicly i'm trying to spin a coin more then once.

With `setOneShot(true)` i can only ever make it run once and with `setOneShot(false)` i can't stop it. Any help or point to right direction would be great!

Here is a little code:

```
    public void spinCoin(){

        final ImageView coinAmina = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        coinAmina.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.coin_spin_heads); 
        coinAmina.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) coinAmina.getBackground();
                frameAnimation.start();
            }
        }); 

        //end of coin spin
        }
```

with setOneShot(true) in xml

link to other Q.

[how do i run AnimationDrawable 3 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268946/how-do-i-run-animationdrawable-3-times)

Comment: You should add the link of your previous question.

Comment: AnimarionDrawable.stop() works just fine, i dont know what kind of problems you can have with it

Comment: I assume you wish to have the animation play in full a discrete number of times? and AnimationDrawable.stop() may interrupt the animation part-way through.

Comment: ive had frameAnimation.stop() after Thread.sleep(1000) but it didnt stop it