# How can I use a single ImageView to display different animationDrawables, started at different times, without triggering a "Wrong Thread Exception?"

Tags: android, animation

Ok, I have a game that I am working on, and I need to be able to put different character state animations onto a single view. Here I have goblin_neutral, and goblin_hit, as 2 animation lists, one to show an enemy in a calm state, and the other to show the enemy getting struck. Both are animation lists in separate .xml files in the drawable folder.

```
AnimationDrawable enemy_neutral_animation, enemy_hit_animation;
ImageView enemy, player;

//...after onCreate()
enemy = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView2);
enemy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goblin_neutral);
enemy_neutral_animation = (Animation)enemy.getBackground();
enemy_neutral.start();

//...now jump to the code that triggers a new animation
enemy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goblin_hit);
enemy_hit_animation = (Animation)enemy.getBackground();
enemy_hit_animation.start();

// all of this works^^, as I can see the second animation displayed

// I use a timer to wait for the animation to finish
mTimer.schedule(timerTask, 600);

//mTask is where it stops everytime
timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            enemy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goblin_anim_neutral);
            enemy_neutral = (AnimationDrawable)enemy.getBackground();
            enemy_neutral.start();

        }
    };
// I get a wrong thread exception
// E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0                                               
ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException:
```

Comment: There are some ways to do it explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214735/android-animationdrawable-and-knowing-when-animation-ends) that might be useful so you don't have to rely on a `TimerTask`.

Answer (score 0):

> ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException:

Because `enemy` ImageView object is accessing from run of `TimerTask` and  `TimerTask` run on separate Thread from UI Thread, but we can only update or access UI elements from UI Thread.

To get it work use  `runOnUiThread` for accessing Views from non-ui Thread.like:

```
timerTask = new TimerTask() {
   @Override
    public void run() {
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // access enemy here
               enemy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goblin_anim_neutral);
               ...
            }
         });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I will approach this is to use a Handler and Runnable.

In your class, create a handler member variable like so

```
Handler handler;
```

Note you want to import Handler as follows:

```
import android.os.Handler;
```

Also create a runnable member variable like so

```
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
        enemy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goblin_anim_neutral);
        enemy_neutral = (AnimationDrawable)enemy.getBackground();
        enemy_neutral.start();
   }
}
```

In your constructor, you could initialise the handler.

```
handler = new Handler();
```

So, when you need to schedule the task, you simply call

```
handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 600);
```