# Determining finish for oneshot and non-oneshot AnimationDrawables

Tags: android, android-animation, animationdrawable

I'm trying to find a solution for switching between AnimationDrawables smoothly.  To do this, I feel it's necessary to know when the AnimationDrawable is finished animating.  I've seen other stack overflow solutions, but I have not found one that works for both `oneshot=true` and `oneshot=false` animations.

Here's my custom AnimationDrawable at this time:

```
public class LifecycleAnimationDrawable extends AnimationDrawable {

    private boolean finishedAnimating = false;

    private AnimationDrawableLifecycleListener animationDrawableLifecycleListener;

    public interface AnimationDrawableLifecycleListener {
        void onAnimationStart();
        void onAnimationFinished();
    }

    public LifecycleAnimationDrawable(AnimationDrawable drawable, AnimationDrawableLifecycleListener animationDrawableLifecycleListener) {
        this.animationDrawableLifecycleListener = animationDrawableLifecycleListener;
        for (int i = 0; i < drawable.getNumberOfFrames(); i++) {
            addFrame(drawable.getFrame(i), drawable.getDuration(i));
        }
        setOneShot(drawable.isOneShot());
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        if (animationDrawableLifecycleListener != null) {
            animationDrawableLifecycleListener.onAnimationStart();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean selectDrawable(int index) {
        boolean result = super.selectDrawable(index);
        if (index != 0 && index == getNumberOfFrames() - 1) {
            if (!finishedAnimating || !isOneShot()) {
                finishedAnimating = true;
                if (animationDrawableLifecycleListener != null) {
                    animationDrawableLifecycleListener.onAnimationFinished();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I have noticed that the index seems to always be 0.

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: refer this. https://github.com/metova/metova-android-sdk/blob/master/metova-android-core/src/com/metova/android/graphics/drawable/CustomAnimationDrawable.java

Comment: @Radhey I have attempted to use that implementation.  It seems that with all of the implementations, as I stated, int index for selectDrawable is always 0 so it never seems to progress.

Comment: What you are trying to do or acheive exactly with AnimationDrawable! ,If you want to forcefully stop animation of AnimationDrawable  then use ((AnimationDrawable)(someButton.getBackground())).stop();

Comment: refer this also ,https://stackoverflow.com/a/6641321/1848157

Comment: @Radhey, I just need to hold off the animation until the current animation completes.  I have also looked at that other post, nothing so far has worked because of the issue of index always being 0, animation never gets registered as finished.

Comment: you are applying this custom animation in multiple views simultaneously!

Comment: I am not...just one view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153678/discussion-between-radhey-and-isupatches).